# How can I locally store and statically serve the angularjs library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, static-libraries, libraries

I am going to be working on an angular project without internet access, so my links to the cdn will not function. I would like to save the angularjs library to a folder inside of my project. Here is what I have tried:

I went to the cdn link, copied all of the text, pasted it into a file, and saved that file as `angular.min.js` . I then commented out the script tag for the cdn in my `index.html` file, and put in a new script tag specifying the path to the new saved file. When I open my project, I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined."

Here are the relevant pieces of my project's file/folder structure:

```
project
|_core
| |_public
|   |_app
|     |_index.html
|_libraries
  |_angular.min.js
```

And here is my script tag:

`<script src="./../../../libraries/angular.min.js"></script>`

And here is the link to the cdn from which I copied the text:

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js`

Comment: Take a look at [yeoman.io](http://yeoman.io/)

Comment: html linked js files should stay on an accessible path which looks to me under public

Comment: @RossRogers yeoman looks very useful, but I would still like to know why my code isn't working.

Comment: @vinjenzo I tried moving my libraries folder into my app folder (see structure above) and changed my code to ```<script src="./../libraries/angular.min.js"></script>``` but I am still getting the same "angular is not defined" error. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Yes, @devigner.  I'm talking about solving your problem at a higher level.  If you go for a yeoman solution it will solve this problem and many others that you're going to be encountering shortly. It just puts you on a good footing.  Small learning curve, but you have a solid platform instead of building your platform onesie-twosie as you discover the need.

Comment: @RossRogers I appreciate that, and am going to take your advice, but regardless it will drive me insane if I don't get an actual answer to this question.

Comment: @devigner you may use the [devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and check the network tab where you can see if request url path to your libs matches your disk path, I guess its not

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a local webserver of any kind? Angular and many scripts need to be loaded from http and not `file://`. For this, you could use python's SimpleHTTPServer: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` -- will open an http server on `http://localhost:8080`, open the url in your browser and you should be good to go. Also note that the order in which you load the scripts in your HTML is important, and Angular needs to be loaded before all modules of code that use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  Grunt task to minify and concatenate all files. You can read the docs of GruntJS. Very useful.

http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile

see the concatenate section.

if you do that manually you have check the sequence of lib files. Angularjs lib need to be on top.
There are chances of errors.

yes  just to include a file you don't need Grunt 
check in chrome inspect developer tool in network tab if your file angular.min.js loaded properly. If not you can change the path and try but if it is loading and still you are getting same error so please create jsfiddle or plunker of your file so that we can look it in detail.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood my question. Although it is a useful tool, grunt is not necessary for this task.

Comment: Did you check in the chrome debug inspect tool if angular.min.js loaded ? If that shows file not found then I think you can check it by changing the file path in index.html

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="../../../libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
```

How about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you just tried this?

```
<script src="/libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe your server start website (localhost:80) from the root of your project